# Nginx try_files remove client_max_body_size option

Tags: nginx

I have a trouble to setup my `nginx.conf` for my symfony application. I want to setup a route `/section/upload/` that allows to increase the size of the client_max_body_size (~100M, standard client_max_body_size = 25M)

```
http {
    ### ....
    client_max_body_size        25M;
    server {
        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;

            location /section/upload {
                client_max_body_size 100M;
                try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
            }
        }

        location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;

            ### ... specific fastcgi_param needed by my symfony application
            ### like : fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;

        }
    }

}
```

I get an error when I send a file larger than 25M on the /section/upload route. To avoid this I have to put the parameter client_max_body_size=100M in location ^/index.php(/|$).

I think try_files doesn't follow my client_max_body_size, is it normal and is it good/safe to setup like that ?

Comment: What does your `location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$)` block look like?

Comment: Your location block for PHP files probably takes over your other location blocks. To be certain about that - you may need to increase the logging level like `error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;` and then check which of the location blocks is actually being used.

Comment: @RichardSmith I update my post.

Comment: @IVOGELOV seem to path through `http->server->location /->location /section/upload->location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$)`

Comment: @IVOGELOV error debug should show which location is used ? i don't get any imformation about which location used. only some `http fastcgi record byte`

Comment: It should say something like `test location: "/section/upload"` and then `using configuration: "/section/upload"` - this last sentence is the important thing.

Comment: my bad, so i got : using configuration "/section/upload", then using configuration "^/index\.php(/|$)". So I think i need to add client_max_body_size in both location. @IVOGELOV

Comment: Well, it will be easier (but not more elegant) if you put `client_max_body_size` in the `server` scope rather than a `location` scope - so it will affect all location blocks.

Comment: If I put client_max_body_size to 100M in server scope it will allow body attack with 100M request in all location instead of only  `/upload` location.

Answer (score 0):

The `try_files` directive rewrites the URI to `/index.php` which is then processed in a different `location`. To set a different value for `client_max_body_size`, you will need to process `/index.php` within the `location /section/upload` block.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
location /section/upload {
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    try_files /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

The `try_files` statement is changed so that `/index.php` appears as a file parameter and not a URI parameter. Most of the FastCGI directives are also required. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Still get an 413 error when I try to send a 30mB file with your example